# Shiny: Is it possible to have reactive code running alongside observeEvent()?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, shinyapps

In the following Shiny app, a long calculation is performed when an action button (run) is pressed.The output is shown at the end of the calculation.

A clock is shown in the app. While the long calculation is ongoing, the clock does not update.

Is it possible to have the clock updating while the calculation is ongoing?

Code:

```
library(shiny)

n <- c(1:42E7)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(inputId = "run", label = "Run a long calculation"),
  verbatimTextOutput("calc"),
  verbatimTextOutput("time")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  x <- observeEvent(input$run,{
    output$calc <- renderText({
      head(sqrt(n))
    })
  })


  output$time <- renderText({
    invalidateLater(1000)
    print(as.character(Sys.time()))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks in anticipation,

Chris

Comment: R being single threaded, what you ask isn't simply possible "out of the box". Though the author of Shiny is working on "async" and "promises" to address such problems. There are already possible workarounds with the `future` package I think

Comment: I thought as much... I can probably tinker with my package to separate the calculation I need into several separate function calls. It's not a clock I need to print IRL, it's a progressively updating log file.

Comment: Actually, `promises` has reached `1.0` since I last checked (Still requires the dev version of Shiny from Github though). I tried to put together an answer to your question but haven't succeeded yet. Ref: https://rstudio.github.io/promises

Answer (score 1):

This answer doesn't work yet, I put it here just so you can pick up after me.

You need to update to the dev version of Shiny (`remotes::install_github("rstudio/shiny")`).

I replaced your toy example with a `Sys.sleep()` because transfering the big vector required to raise option `future.globals.maxSize` and was still causing my machine to crash anyway.

```
library(shiny)
library(promises)
library(future)
plan(multiprocess)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(inputId = "run", 
               label = "Run a long calculation"),
  verbatimTextOutput("calc"),
  verbatimTextOutput("time")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$run,{
    output$calc <- renderText({
      future({
        Sys.sleep(5)
        42
      }) %...>% 
        head() %...>% 
        print()
    })
  })

  output$time <- renderPrint({
    invalidateLater(1000)
    as.character(Sys.time())
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I expected it to work, but the "expensive operation" is still blocking, I haven't figured out why yet. Hopefully it'll still be useful.

ref: https://rstudio.github.io/promises

Comment: Great Auréle, thank you. I'll certainly have a play.

Unfortunately my client will not be keen on using anything outside of CRAN that isn't built by me. I'm working on alternative workarounds... and crossing my fingers that CRAN shiny is updated soon!